# How to fix trainserver empty server?

Tags: trains, clearml

Im trying to install an allegroai trains-server on a k8s cluster.

I tried the following 3 methods

- [bare linux installtion](https://allegro.ai/docs/deploying_trains/trains_server_linux_mac/)
- [k8s manifest installation](https://allegro.ai/docs/deploying_trains/trains_server_kubernetes/)
- [helm installation](https://allegro.ai/docs/deploying_trains/trains_server_kubernetes_helm/)

I followed the linux installation to the letter,
and in the k8s installations used the following command to access the exposed port of the trains webserver
kubectl port-forward -n trains svc/webserver-service 9999:80

In all three cases i manage to get to the server, but it looks empty and most operations fail.[Here is a screen shot of what the webserver looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OMhYi.png).

I tried doing all 3 multiple times from scratch and even rebuilt my k8s cluster but nothing works.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Try asking at [unix.se] or [sf].

Comment: The trains repo says to ask here with the trains tag.

Comment: Turns out this was a token caching problem. When you log in to a new server but have an auth token of the old server, you get a broken interface instead of it bringing you to a new login screen. Cleaning my cookies solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer - I'm part of the allegro.ai Trains team

The current implementation of trains-server supports two types of deployments

1. Single IP with fixed set of ports:

- Port 8080 - Web service,
- Post 8008 - API
- Port 8081 - Generic http file serving

2. sub-domain deployment:

- http://app.sub.domain.com - Web service
- http://api.sub.domain.com - API service
- http://files.sub.domain.com - Generic http/s file serving

There is also a helm chart deployment that will deploy the trains-server on a single node exposing ports 30080/30008/30081
You can find the details [here](https://github.com/allegroai/trains-server-helm)